# Custom PHP Extension not working for 5.3

Tags: php, c++, c, php-5.3, php-extension

I have a custom PHP extension which compares each byte in a binary data string. If both bytes at the same location in the file are on (or greater than 1) then the output of the same position will be on. Otherwise its off. The extension is as follows...

```
PHP_FUNCTION(compare_memory)
{
    char *memory1, *memory2;
    int memory1_length, memory2_length, return_length;
    int length;
    char *output;
    int x;

    zval *param;

    // MAKE SURE WE HAVE
    // string, (string_len,), string2, (string2_len) and length
    if(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 2) WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;

    // GET ARGUMENTS FROM PHP 
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &memory1, &memory1_length, &memory2, &memory2_length) == FAILURE)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (memory1_length < memory2_length)
    {
        length = memory1_length;
        return_length = memory2_length;
    } else
    {
        length = memory2_length;
        return_length = memory1_length;
    }

    if ((output = emalloc(return_length * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error on malloc\n");
        return;
    }

    // START COMPARING
    for(x=1;x<length;x++)
    {
        if (memory1[x] > 0 && memory2[x] == 1)
        {
            output[x] = memory1[x];
        }
    }

    RETVAL_STRINGL(output, return_length, 1);
    efree(output);
}
```

I also have a PHP implementation as follows...

```
function compare_memory($data1, $data2)
{
    $pack_one = pack("c", 1);
    $pack_zero = pack("c", 0);
    $strlen_data1 = strlen($data1);
    $strlen_data2 = strlen($data2);
    if ($strlen_data1 > $strlen_data2)
    {
        $strlen = $strlen_data1;
    } else
    {
        $strlen = $strlen_data2;
    }
    $output = "";

    for($x=0;$x<$strlen;$x++)
    {
        if ($strlen_data1 > $x)
        {
            $arr = unpack("cc", $data1[$x]);
            $d1 = $arr["c"];
        } else
        {
            $d1 = 0;
        }

        if ($strlen_data2 > $x)
        {
            $arr = unpack("cc", $data2[$x]);
            $d2 = $arr["c"];
        } else
        {
            $d2 = 0;
        }

        if ($d1 > 0 && $d2 == 1)
        {
            $output .= pack("c", $d1);
        } else
        {
            $output .= $pack_zero;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

This extension was working fine with PHP 5.0 (which I'm aware is very old). We've recently upgraded to 5.3 and this no longer works. However the PHP implementation does.

I imagine there have been a whole host of changes to the PHP Internal API between the versions, including "Parameter parsing API unification will cause some functions to behave more or less strict when it comes to type juggling".

Can you see anything obvious in the PHP Extension that may cause it to not work in more recent versions of PHP? My knowledge of C (and the PHP API) is sparse.

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of the extension "not working"?

Comment: The output of the extension gives back a string with all bytes set to on for a length of the longest input string.

Comment: have a look at violet313s answer then, it might be related.

Comment: as there is no `else output[x] = 0;` in your for-loop (which also, unlike the `php` implementation, only iterates to `length`) this would be consistent with uninitalised `emalloc`'ed `output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can guarantee that `emalloc` is going to return you memory initialised with zeros. you might try using [ecalloc](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.management.php) instead. 
Or do it yourself:

```
if ((output = emalloc(return_length * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error on malloc\n");
    return;
}
memset(output, 0, return_length * sizeof(int) );
```

Also, i don't think `emalloc` *ever* returns `NULL`

(Also i'm not sure why your `for(x=1;x<length;x++)` starts from 1 instead of zero but perhaps there's a reason)

Comment: what exactly makes you think he needs zeroed out memory?

Comment: @[PlasmaHH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/833362/plasmahh) ~inferred from the php implementation, apparently working.. but as you noted, OP should say a bit about how it's 'not working'

Comment: ecalloc worked perfectly. It appeared on an old version of slackware the kernal would allocate memory zero'd out when using emalloc. Which isn't what emalloc is intended to do. Using ecalloc instead solved the problem. Thanks for your help :)